# Laravel: Filter through collection by search term

Tags: laravel, search, collections, filter, wildcard

I have the following problem:
I want to create an instant-search, where I get immediate results via AJAX as soon as the user starts typing. Instead of performing an extra database-query within six tables for each 'keyup' I wanted to eager-load all the database records and provide them in my view.
That way I only need to search if my collection items contain the search term and return these as results. 
I know I can narrow the collection down with the `where()`-method, e.g.

`$words = $words->where('lemma', 'mysearchterm');
return $words;`

The problem is, I don't want to retrieve exact matches, but use wildcards like in standard SQL-Queries (`SELECT * FROM nouns WHERE lemma LIKE %$mysearchterm%`).

How do I do this?
I have been trying for two hours now. 
Does this even make sense? Or is there no performance-advantage to just querying the DB every single time once the user starts typing? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking how to use `like` in a query? suh as `$words->where('lemma', 'like', '%'.$mysearchterm.'%');` ? Also you could have a look into [Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scout) which is a full text search engine. No pattern matching required. It does use [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) which is free to a certain point, but pretty reasonable.

Comment: I'm wirth @Ohgodwhy here. You probably would want to look at Scout. You could easily pair it with [TNT Search driver for Scout](https://github.com/teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver) if you don't want to use Algolia and stick to your local database.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers. I will definitely have a look at Scout. I solved my problem with this code:

```
$result = $words->filter(function ($value, $key) {

    if (strpos($value->lemma, $mysearchterm) !== false) {
        return $value;
    }
});
```